# Record numbers in ascending order in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I have following query:

```
  var accounts =
    from account in context.Accounts
    from guranteer in account.Gurantors

 select new AccountsReport
    {
        CreditRegistryId = account.CreditRegistryId,
        AccountNumber = account.AccountNo,
        DateOpened = account.DateOpened,
    };

 return accounts.AsEnumerable()
                   .Select((account, index) => new AccountsReport()
                           {
                               RecordNumber = FormattedRowNumber(account, index + 1),
                               CreditRegistryId = account.CreditRegistryId,
                               AccountNumber = FormattedAccountNumber(account.AccountType, account.AccountNumber)}).OrderByDescending(c => c.StateChangeDate);

It works fine except one problem and that is it returns records number in reverse order like 3, 2,1 because of .OrderByDescending(c => c.StateChangeDate);
```

Can I show the record number in ascendeing order while keeping the records in descending order.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) on `RecordNumber` and then [ThenByDescending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534736.aspx) on `StateChangeDate`

`.OrderBy(c => c.RecordNumber).ThenByDescending(c => c.StateChangeDate);`